# Location name using later/long coordinates offline.

Tags: gps

Is it possible to get location name using GPS lat and long  coordinates without using internet ??  I am using atmega 8 microcontroller and a GPS module with which I am able to get lat/long  coordinates. So,using this I want to find the name of the location  and using a GSM module I am going to send it to specified people.This is my project plan. is there any easy means to achieve this?? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

A GSM module can build a data connection, via GPRS.
there you can send a message, to your server, which can be a locaton request.
The server receives the lat,long value, and looks up the coordinate using a service or somehow.
The server sends as answer, the name of the location back.

If a data connection is not availabe, one can send an SMS to your server.